# Will addEventListener() always have ev.currentTarget and "this" as the element we observe on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-delegation

Is it true that in plain JavaScript, if we observe on `elementFoo`:

```
elementFoo.addEventListener("click", function(ev) {
    console.log(ev.currentTarget, this);
});
```

then `ev.currentTarget` and `this` will always be `elementFoo`?

It is a bit hard to remember because in jQuery, if we delegate the event:

```
$("#table-foo").on("click", "tr", function(ev) {
    console.log(ev.currentTarget, this);
});
```

then `ev.currentTarget` and `this` will both be the `tr` element.  Is it true that using `addEventListener()`, it cannot have this behavior?  (the only way is to have `ev.target` being the `td` element, but never `tr`?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it true that in plain JavaScript, if we observe on
>   elementFoo:...then ev.currentTarget and this will always be
>   elementFoo?

Yes. You can read about it [*here*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) :

> It **always** refers to the element the event handler has been attached to
>   as opposed to event.target which identifies the element on which the
>   event occurred.

I don't see the contradiction :

If for example you have [**this**](http://jsbin.com/mupoc/5/edit?html,output) :

[image]

And you click on the `span` :  then :

```
 $( "body" ).on( "click", "p", function(e) {
   console.log( "delegateTarget" , e.delegateTarget.nodeName ) //BODY
   console.log( "currentTarget" ,e.currentTarget.nodeName)    //P
   console.log( "target" , e.target.nodeName)          //SPAN
   console.log( "this" , $(this)[0].nodeName)        //P - the middle atached element
});
```

Will yield :

```
 delegateTarget BODY
 currentTarget P
 target SPAN
 this P
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you trying to achieve is called "event delegation".
In javascript events are bubbles. So parent element can know on which element you triggered event, in your case you need attach even on top element and inside of logic check for which element is clicked. The similar one way(but more complex) it work in jQuery and any other framework which have event delegation.

Here is a short example of how to use https://jsfiddle.net/49w3zvmL/

```
var elementFoo = document.getElementById('foo');
elementFoo.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if(e.target && e.target.nodeName === 'SPAN') {
        alert('click on span');
    }else{
      alert('click on div');
    }
});
```

And here are links to further reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/bubbles